# Syntax region only if at top of file

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a syntax I'm trying do make. It's `yaml` embedded in `markdown` for use with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/). The `yaml` region is enclosed by `---` and this *must* be at the top of the file.

```
---
[yaml front matter stuff]
.
.
.
---
# Here starts the markdown
```

I've defined a region that specifies where the `yaml` region should start:
`syn region yamlBlock matchgroup=quasiQuote start=/^---/ end=/^---/ contains=@yaml`
(inspired by [this embedded haskell syntax file](https://github.com/pbrisbin/vim-syntax-shakespeare/blob/master/after/syntax/haskell.vim))

**I want this region to only apply if it is at the very top of the file.**

I've tried adding an `if` statement:

```
if getline(1) =~ '---'
    syn region yamlBlock matchgroup=quasiQuote start=/^---/ end=/^---/ contains=@yaml
endif
```

But this will only update when the buffer is reloaded. ie. If I have it open and add a blank line at the top of the file, the code inside

```
---
[....]
---
```

will still be highlighted as `yaml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try tweaking your region start pattern to match the start of the file:

```
start=/\%^---/
```

See [`:help start-of-file`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#start-of-file).